# What is the fastest way to get stronger?

Tags: monster-hunter-world

I just started playing Monster Hunter World, and I was told it is very grind heavy, and I just want to ask in advance **how to prevent most of the grinding** and which way to take, what to avoid, how and where to skip unnecessary grinding etc. to become stronger fastest.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to get strongest fastest is 'get good'.

Monster Hunter always has been a grind heavy game, because good equipment requires a lot of monster parts. There is no quick way to the top.

The best way to do this is to try all of the different weapon types, pick the one you feel most comfortable with and practice with it(and by practicing i just mean play, dont do the same monster over again unless you need his parts).

Watch tutorials by gaijin hunter to learn the finer details of the weapons.

What you can do, although i dont recommend it unless you know how to play well, is to only do all the Key/Mandatory quest. This way you can do the more difficult monster sooner, but it makes the game way harder if you dont know how to deal with them.

Happy Hunting

Comment: The sad fact is the top equipment matters much less than skill.  A naked hunter that truly mastered the game will be better than a guy with an inherited account with maxed out gear.  There's no substitution for knowing what to do against specific monster.  One trick like this is flashing a Flying Wyvern that is getting out of a pit trap.  You can do an aerial stagger, simply by sheathing at the right time and throwing the flash bomb at the right spot.  This practically doubles the monster's vulnerability period.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to avoid some of the most difficult part of grinding (getting the rarest drops from monsters) is to do the Weekly Bounties. Completing all of them will net you a golden voucher, this can be used to trade for a rare monster part (like a gem).

The only problem with this is you need to be a decently established hunter to begin with in order to clear all of the Bounties, as they may have you fight tougher end-game monsters.

As others have mentioned. Monster Hunter is *built and designed* around the hunting/grinding loop. If that style of game is not your thing, then Monster Hunter is probably not the title for you. Even though they have made tweaks and changes to make the grind less so. it's still very much there.

Stronger, is also up in the air, when it comes to Monster Hunter. Once you find a weapon type your comfortable with, you will instantly get that "stronger" feeling, even in the starter equipment. Me, for example, love and feel so good using the gunlance... but if you give me twin swords. I'm probably going to triple cart before the Monster even enrages.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already cover most things about the topic, but I'd like to add onoe more thing.

*Grinding*, i.e. doing quests over and over again in order to get materials, also serves another purpose: *training*.

If you need to grind, say, 5 Anjanaths, this repetition makes you learn the monster: its tells, its hitboxes, its rhythm...

This knowledge and mastery plays a great role (possibly more than gear) at becoming a strong player.

Answer (score 0):

Release of *Iceborne* includes Defender weapons and Guardian armors to get on par with weapons that had to be grinded back then in the base game. That way, you can postpone the "grinding" to the Master Rank, which happens right after the base game's ending.

Also, weapons with low rarity tend to get completed and augmented fast. Do not overlook them. Armors with low rarity such as Beotodus set or Anjanath set have surprisingly good skills, helping you not having to deal with "expensive" armors involving mantles.

Answer (score -1):

As it has been already been pointed out. Monster Hunter is all about the grinding for gear and the only way around that is skill.

If you only want to beat the story, then you can do it with like 2 armors and 2 weapons as well.

I myself did the story at first with buying the Bone Armor for some Zenny (no grind) and building some weapon I was good with. Then at some point before the high rank monsters I needed a new armor because I got 1 hit. That was the point where I built the Diablos Armor. Always keep your weapons upgarded as good as possible. Then at some point the Diablos Armor was repalced by the Rathalos Soul Alpha Armor (Azur Rathalos) and the weapon got updgraded to the last possible level and that was the point where I was able to beat the last monster.

[If you want to read up on a huge bunch of guides, then go here!](https://www.reddit.com/r/MonsterHunter/comments/7xd08l/monster_hunter_world_a_guide_of_guides/)

Comment: Thank you, this is the first comment that is actually trying to help, instead of needlessly bashing on the fact that someone wants to avoid unnecessary grinding, wherever possible. 

I will follow your advice and get 3 armor pieces (start, middle, end) and focus on a single weapon which i will upgrade whenever possible.

Comment: Do note that this guide only helps you with the story. Once you finish the story a whole bunch of different/stronger monster will be open for you to hunt. For them you will need to improve even further and actually need to grind for those sweet decorations